# Problem with blur in video editing

Tags: uv-image-editor, blur

Hi i really hope someone can help me out with this: I'm trying to blur a section of my video, the part where my motorbike speedometer is, and basically i followed this tutorial on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_06cWLUZ_Bg BUT the thing is that no matter what ,the section which get blurred(on the right) does not correspond to the section i selected(on the left)[image: the part which will be blurred( on the right) does not correspond with the part i selected (on the left)]

Because i thought it was kind of a sync problem between the "actual" video and its "reference" video in the UV/editor i selected Start = 0 (in the UV/editor properties ) but nothing changed, also by selecting Offset = 0 too.

So...what the hell is going on here? 
thanks!

p.s. If you need more details just ask.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have a different aspect ratio in image and final render. You can do 2 things:

1) set render size equal to video demissions

[image]

2) tune  **aspect ratio** of image in **display** settings in **movie clip editor**

[image]

Comment: Ok don't get mad but... where do i find the ratio of the video on the right ? I mean when i import the video at first it's too small so i zoom in with the mouse wheel and then do the same when i import the video on the left window . But after i did this i can't find the aspect ratio of the left video anywhere. Appreciate the patience.

Comment: @entropic.chaos Ratio of the video on the right goes from render demissions. So set up it equal to video demissions